# How to groupby other column and get the last date without NaT in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I want to group by ID column and get the last date without NaT in pandas. When I try `dropna` , I got an error`Cannot access callable attribute 'dropna' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects,try using the 'apply' method` If I don't drop or ignore the NaT, this will use NaT to be the last date. How can I ignore the NaT and find the last date?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
# making data frame from csv file
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv",delimiter='|')

df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'],errors = 'coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['most_recent_date'] = df.groupby(df['VIP_ID_SOURCE'])['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'].dropna().transform('max')

df['keep'] = np.where(
    df['most_recent_date'] == df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'],
    'yes,jsut same tier',
    'same tier,last purchase date dup by ' + df['VIP_ID_SOURCE'].astype(str)
)

df['both'] = df['VIP_ID_SOURCE']+df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'].astype(str)

df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['both'], keep = False),'keep'] = 'same tier same last purchase date '
df = df.drop(columns = ['both','most_recent_date'])
print(df)
```

sample csv(Null is a word not really null):

```
VIP_ID_SOURCE|TIER|LAST_PURCHASE_DATE|keep
F08210020403|FO|2014-05-17 00:00:00|yes
F08210020905|FO|2014-04-18 00:00:00|yes
F08210020905|FO|Null|yes
F08210020403|FO|Null|yes
C01073019552|FO|2016-09-18 00:00:00|yes
C01073019552|FO|2016-05-10 00:00:00|yes
F08210022302|FO|Null|yes
F08210022302|FO|Null|yes
```

expect output:

```
VIP_ID_SOURCE|TIER|LAST_PURCHASE_DATE|keep
F08210020403|FO|2014-05-17 00:00:00|yes,jsut same tier
F08210020905|FO|2014-04-18 00:00:00|yes,jsut same tier
F08210020905|FO|Null|same tier,last purchase date dup by F08210020905
F08210020403|FO|Null|same tier,last purchase date dup by F08210020403
C01073019552|FO|2016-09-18 00:00:00|yes,jsut same tier
C01073019552|FO|2016-05-10 00:00:00|same tier,last purchase date dup by C01073019552
F08210022302|FO|Null|same tier same last purchase date 
F08210022302|FO|Null|same tier same last purchase date
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try doing `transform('max')` first  and then  `dropna()`.  Like `df['most_recent_date'] = df.groupby(df['VIP_ID_SOURCE'])['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'].transform('max').dropna()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are several issues in your code.

First I would propose that you transform your date in `LAST_DATE_PURCHASE` into datetime and not into a string. Then you can apply `.max(numeric_only=True)` instead of transform. I assign the resulting dataframe to a new one, which I join afterwards with `df` via `df = df.join(most_recent_date, on="VIP_ID_SOURCE")`.

So the final code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# making data frame from csv file
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv",delimiter='|')

df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'],errors = 'coerce')
most_recent_date = df.groupby(df['VIP_ID_SOURCE'])['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'].max()
most_recent_date= most_recent_date.rename("most_recent_date")
df = df.join(most_recent_date, on="VIP_ID_SOURCE")
df['keep'] = np.where(
    df['most_recent_date'] == df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'],
    'yes,jsut same tier',
    'same tier,last purchase date dup by ' + df['VIP_ID_SOURCE'].astype(str)
)

df['both'] = df['VIP_ID_SOURCE']+df['LAST_PURCHASE_DATE'].astype(str)

df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['both'], keep = False),'keep'] = 'same tier same last purchase date '
df = df.drop(columns = ['both','most_recent_date'])
print(df)
```